# Is it safe to delete this empty `google_storage_default_object_acl` with terraform?

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-storage, access-control

I used terraformer to import my terraform state for an existing project.

It's imported a long list of ACLs, many of which have no entities in the list:

```
resource "google_storage_default_object_acl" "tfer--my-bucket" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"
}
```

[Docs for this resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_default_object_acl) say that having no `role_entity` entry is the same as providing an empty list.

So, are these resources completely useless? **Can I safely delete them?**